# Facebook is unable to retrieve my iPhone Store ID from the iTunes App Store

Tags: ios, facebook

I have never had this problem before and the app has been live in the US for over 12 hours. I put in the App ID from iTunes Connect and it throws the following error.

> We were unable to retrieve your iPhone Store ID from the iTunes App
>   Store. Please double-check your ID and try again later.

I tried putting in a different App ID from one of my other apps and it works just fine. For some reason it won't recognize this one..